# different currency per product

Tags: price, currency, ce-1.9.1.0, affiliate

I am building a new Magento store. 80% of the products are affiliate products, where the price needs to be displayed in it's original currency. 20% of the products are regular products in the store's base currency (e.g. €), which can be added to the shopping cart.

Example:

- `Product C   19€ ==> Add to cart / buy now.`
- `Product A   10& ==> Affiliate link`
- `Product B   15$ ==> Affiliate link`

The 'Buy Now' button for each affiliate product will simply be an affiliate link (no need to add these products to the shopping cart).

I want different products to display their prices in different currencies (one price per product).

Questions:

1. With vanilla megento, is it possible to have different currency symbol displayed for each product?
2. I plan to implement affiliate products by creating a [custom product type](http://www.solvingmagento.com/creating-a-custom-product-type-in-magento/) using [this code](http://www.solvingmagento.com/creating-a-custom-product-type-in-magento/). Will it help?
3. Any other option?

Please advise

Also, is there a calculator which allows the user to convert the price to their local currency? (to get an estimation).

Comment: I don't have the base magento interface in front of me. I see there are extensions like http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-base-currency.html but  they seem to provide too many features and might be complex to setup and upgrade. So is there a simpler option?

Answer (score 2):

Since it has no impact on your price calculation, the simplest solution is to add a product attribute, for example "`Affiliate Currency`". Then you probably have to rewrite `price.phtml`. The `formatPrice()` function is tied deep into the store model and I don't see an easy way to rewrite that, since you have no product information available, meaning you'd need a different method signature.

I'd probably make a wrapper `formatPriceForProduct()`, where you can pass the product model and offload to the default formatPrice if no `Affiliate Currency` is set and do your own formatting if it is.